# Problema com select em PHP

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined index: album_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery.php on line 69

Line 69:

```html
        $album_name = $db->data[0]['album_name'];
```

codigo desta parte:

```html
$db->query( "select * from fotos" )->fetchAll();
    if ( $db->rows >= 1 )
    {
        $album_name = $db->data[0]['album_name'];

        echo "<h1>" .  $album_name  . "</h1>\n";
        echo "<a href=\"album.php\" class=\"back\"><img src=\"images/left.png\"/> Voltar</a>";
```

preciso fazer um select para o colocar o nome do album no meu site, mas estou com esse problema

Comment: Abaixo do `$db->query( "select * from fotos" )->fetchAll();` mas antes do IF coloca um print_r($db); e manda o resultado.

Comment: mysql Object ( [query] => select * from fotos [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [foto_id] => 4 [foto_url] => test.jpg [foto_caption] => [foto_data] => 2017-02-07 00:00:00 [foto_album] => 1 [foto_pos] => 0 [foto_info] => ) [1] => Array ( [foto_id] => 5 [foto_url] => test2.jpg [foto_caption] => [foto_data] => 2017-02-07 00:00:00 [foto_album] => 1 [foto_pos] => 1 [foto_info] => ) ) [result] => Resource id #8 [rows] => 2 [config:protected] => Array ( [host] => localhost [port] => 3306 [dbname] => photoupload [user] => root [password] => ) [host:protected] => localhost [port:protected] =>

Comment: 3306 [user:protected] => root [pass:protected] => [dbname:protected] => photoupload [con:protected] => Resource id #6 )

Comment: Como você pode ver dentro desse teu objeto não existe "album_name", tem certeza que a tabela é **Fotos**?

Comment: é outra tabela o album, só fazer outro select dentro deste para o $album_name ?

Comment: vou colocar uma resposta aqui embaixo pra ficar mais bem escrito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP está informando que o índice `album_name` não existe, dê um `var_dump($db->data[0])` e veja se tem algum campo com o nome `album_name`.

Caso esteja em uma tabela de álbuns, apenas tente fazer um JOIN:

```
$db->query("select * from fotos, albuns WHERE fotos.foto_album=albuns.album_id")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Não tem, pq o select está nas fotos, resultado : array(7) { ["foto_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["foto_url"]=> string(8) "test.jpg" ["foto_caption"]=> string(0) "" ["foto_data"]=> string(19) "2017-02-07 00:00:00" ["foto_album"]=> string(1) "1" ["foto_pos"]=> string(1) "0" ["foto_info"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: só fazer um outro select certo ?

Comment: onde está o campo `album_name`? se for em uma tabela de álbuns, mostre os campos que talvez seja possível fazer um SQL trazendo as informações das duas tabelas.

Comment: album_name está na tabela albuns, só fazer um join no select então ?

Comment: isso, faça um join e retorne as informações das duas tabelas

Comment: ok, irei fazer e ja posto se deu certo

Comment: Certinho, muito obrigado, funcionou !

Answer (score 1):

Faça um JOIN da seguinte forma:

```
$db->query("select a.*, b.album_name AS album_name from fotos a INNER JOIN tabela_com_album_name b ON a.foto_album = b.id_do_album")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou Grato ! era isso ! obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tem certeza que `album_name` é o nome correto da coluna no seu banco de dados? Como já disseram, da um `var_dump` ou `print_r` para ver exatamente o que está vindo de sua consulta.

Comment: não está, preciso fazer outra consulta para outra tabela, só fazer outro select ?